# Image uploaded to s3 bucket is NOT being saved in bucket as image

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-s3

I just started learning about uploading files and images to s3 bucket in android. I have been able to learn how to upload files and it works (I see it in my bucket), however, the problem is that it saves as a file which cannot be opened, instead of an image that it is.

I get the uri from the onActivityResult just like this:

```
Uri selectedImg=data.getData();
String[]filePathColumn={MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

Cursor cursor=getContentResolver().query(selectedImg,filePathColumn,null,null,null);
cursor.moveToFirst();

int columnIndex=cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
imgString=cursor.getString(columnIndex);
```

and create the File using the 'imgString' variable:

```
File imageFile = new File(imgString);
```

and then I pass imageFile into the s3 upload method:

```
TransferObserver observer = transferUtility.upload(
                MY_BUCKET, objectkey, imageFile);
```

and it does upload. But when I go to the bucket, it is not saved as an image (say 'imageFile.jpg'), but just as a file which cannot be read or accessed ('imageFile'). What am I doing wrong? am I supposed to pass in the file extension to let the bucket know its an image? I looked online but that does not seem to matter, plus the uri does contain the .jpg ( or .png) extension, so I'm not sure why it does not seem to work

Comment: If the URL does contain the extension `.jpg` or `.png` then that contradicts your statement that the image is being saved as `imageFile` not `imageFile.jpg`. Either it is being saved with the extension or not, and it sounds like it is. The part you are missing is setting the Mime type or `content-type` on the file when you upload it.

Comment: @MarkB I mean URI not URL. The URI for the image before upload, not the URL in the bucket after upload

Comment: The value in your `objectkey` variable is the filename it will have on S3. Are you dropping the extension from that string somehow?

Comment: @MarkB that works for me! Thank you so much!